# api platform getting 502 bad gateway during https://localhost:8443/ browse

Tags: php, api, docker, api-platform.com

I am running api-platfor version 2.5 with docker after run it and browse https://localhost:8443/. I am getting 502 bad gateway error. here is my error in terminal

```
  api_1 | 2019/11/03 03:57:11 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
  172.18.0.7, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.5:9000", host: "api"
```

can you let me know please how can i solve it

Comment: are you sure about all docker containers works as expected? Check with docker ps command.

Comment: yes, I have checked with docker ps command, all container have up

Comment: did you checked logs in the php container?

Comment: the log folder have empty

Comment: logs may be dumped to syslog, you can view logs with "docker logs -f containerid"